# Using sed to extract element content of an XML file

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Well, using `sed` I'm trying to extract everything between `<Transport_key>` and `</Transport_key>` from input files like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<Header>
<Security>
<Transport_key>
<EncryptedKey Id="TK" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
<CipherData>
<CipherValue>pifKajuAK8FKwqLEhKIP4x5V5XUQyrwhpA</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedKey>
</Transport_key>
</Security>
</Header>
<Body>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

so i want to get

```
<EncryptedKey Id="TK" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
<CipherData>
<CipherValue>pifKajuAK8FKwqLEhKIP4x5V5XUQyrwhpA</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedKey>
```

regardless of any optional newlines between elements. I just want the text between the two strings unmodified, even if the input is a single big line.

I tried with

```
sed -e "s@.*<Transport_key>\(.*\)</Transport_key>.*@\1@" test.txt
```

but in the meantime I learned, that `sed` is taking inputs line per line and it cannot work.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: you are right, but this is my last try without such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your "*last try without such ...*", ***grep*** approach:

```
grep -Poz '<Transport_key>\s*\K[\s\S]*(?=</Transport_key>)' test.txt
```

The output:

```
<EncryptedKey Id="TK" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
<CipherData>
<CipherValue>pifKajuAK8FKwqLEhKIP4x5V5XUQyrwhpA</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedKey>
```

---

For your further ***proper*** tries, [***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) approach:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//Transport_key/*' -n test.txt
```

Comment: I use python XML parser now. It's robust and as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It would be safier to use an xml parser but for some cases it can also be done with regex.

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print for m@<EncryptedKey(?!</EncryptedKey).*</EncryptedKey>@gs' <test.txt
```

from `perl -h`

- -0777 : specify record separator (octal, 777 is undef <=> read all file)
- -n : assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program

modifiers

- g: all matches
- s: `.` matches `\n`

regex:

- (?!..): negative look-ahead

Answer (score 0):

Via sed, you can try the following :

```
sed -n '/<Transport_key>/,/<\/Transport_key>/p' test1.xml | sed -e '/Transport_key/d'
```

The first command takes everything between the Transport_key tags. Since this also prints the Transport_key tags, the second command deletes the lines containing the Transport_key tags.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this particular problem that's independent of white space is to use GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\\s*</?Transport_key>\\s*' 'NR==2' file
<EncryptedKey Id="TK" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
<CipherData>
<CipherValue>pifKajuAK8FKwqLEhKIP4x5V5XUQyrwhpA</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedKey>

$ tr -d '\n' < file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Envelope xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><Header><Security><Transport_key><EncryptedKey Id="TK" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" /><CipherData><CipherValue>pifKajuAK8FKwqLEhKIP4x5V5XUQyrwhpA</CipherValue></CipherData></EncryptedKey></Transport_key></Security></Header><Body></Body></Envelope>

$ tr -d '\n' < file | gawk -v RS='\\s*</?Transport_key>\\s*' 'NR==2'
<EncryptedKey Id="TK" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" /><CipherData><CipherValue>pifKajuAK8FKwqLEhKIP4x5V5XUQyrwhpA</CipherValue></CipherData></EncryptedKey>
```

The reason to use an XML parser, though, is to handle things like the tag value showing up inside a string, etc. properly.

Comment: *to handle things like the tag value* - it has much wider advantages (tag attributes, parent-child relations, following-previous siblings, nested childs ...)

Comment: hence **things like**.